# Better way to get Interval bounds when only time is given

Tags: c#, datetime, intervals

I have to find out the limits of interval i.e `upper-bound and lower-bound` of an interval based on interval type when `datetime` is given.

**Example**: say given time = *12:05* (then, this lies in the interval range *12:00 - 1:00* if interval type is hourly; *12:00 - 12:30* if interval type is half-an hour based;
*12:00 - 12:15* if interval type is quarterly. likewise interval type can be anything.

Currently i am loading all different set of interval ranges in a dictionary object on an application load and then i fetch interval range from this dictionary for the given time.

Sorry, I know this problem statement looks simple but couldn't think of other approaches as of now. It would be helpful if someone can help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I have more info about what are you looking for? Maybe it could be another aproach less... dirty.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper basically i need to figure out the interval for any given time of the day. say given time is 11:58 , then check for interval type. if requested interval type is _A_ return the interval range as 11:00 - 12:00 ; if interval type is _B_ then return interval range as 11:30 - 12:00, if interval type is _C_ then return 11:45 - 12:00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the range start by dividing the total minutes by your interval and then subtracting the remainder from the total minutes. After that, you can easily get the end of the range.

First, you need to get the time part from your `DateTime` object as `TimeSpan` by using [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.timeofday). Then use [`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalminutes).

Here's a good start:

```
public class TimeRange
{
    public TimeRange(TimeSpan from, TimeSpan to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public TimeSpan From { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan To { get; set; }
}

public TimeRange GetRange(DateTime d, int minutesInterval)
{
    TimeSpan time = d.TimeOfDay;
    var from = time.TotalMinutes - (time.TotalMinutes % minutesInterval);
    var to = from + minutesInterval;

    return new TimeRange(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(from), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(to));
}
```

For clarity, I created a simple class called `TimeRange` to represent the start and end of the interval range. You can, however, feel free to handle this in a different way.

**Usage:**

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

TimeRange range = GetRange(d, 60);
//TimeRange range = GetRange(d, 15);
Console.WriteLine("From: {0}\r\nTo: {1}", range.From, range.To);
```

**[Try it online](http://rextester.com/WON95118).**

Comment: This is what i exactly wanted. Thanks a lot for your time.